# Check proof that $\tan(x+\sin(x))$ is periodic and find its period

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I need to:

> Show that $\tan(x+\sin(x))$ is periodic and find its period

I've tried to do that by definition of periodic functions, so:

$$
\tan(x + \sin(x)) = \\ = \tan(x+T+ \sin(x+T)) = \\ =\tan(x+T+\sin(x)\cos(T)+\cos(x)\sin(T))
$$

From the above i see that $\cos(T) = 1$ and $\sin(T) = 0$ so $T= 2\pi n$. Let's check the function for $T=2\pi n$:

$$
\tan(x+\sin(x)) = \tan(x+2\pi n + \sin(x)\cos(2\pi n) + \cos(x)\sin(2\pi n))
$$

Let $n = 1$ for $T$ to not be equal to $0$:

$$
\tan(x+\sin(x)) = \tan(x+2\pi + \sin(x)\cos(2\pi) + \cos(x)\sin(2\pi)) = \tan(x + \sin(x) + 2\pi)
$$

But $\tan(2\pi + \alpha) = \tan(\alpha)$, so the above equation holds for $T=2\pi n$. Basically I have 2 questions:

> 1. Is the reasoning above correct?
> 2. I'm in doubt because [W|A query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period%20tan%28x%2Bsin%28x%29%29) says the function is not periodic, who's right?

Comment: You are correct. See this [visualisation in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uizzflgyjb) - it is periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the function is periodic. Your approach complicates things a lot. All you have to do is to note that $\tan\bigl(x+2\pi+\sin(x+2\pi)\bigr)=\tan\bigl(x+\sin(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: And, how do you know there isn't a period smaller than $2\pi$? Remember that the period is the smallest $t$ such that $f(x+t)=f(x)$. Also there is a problem arising from the fact that the function $tan$ is undefined at an infinity of values.

Comment: @BernardMassé correct me if I'm wrong, but smallest positive $t$ with such property is called the **fundamental** period

Comment: The question is "find its period" and not "find a period", hinting that there is only one answer possible.

Comment: @BernardMassé That's a good point, but it's not hard to see that no number of the form $\frac{2\pi}n$, with $n\in\mathbb N$ and $n>1$, is a period of the function. And, since the function is continuous, if $2\pi$ was not the smallest period, then the function would have a period of the form $\frac{2\pi}n$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in the above comment what continuity plays a role in ruling out that the function cannot have a period less than $2\pi$ ?

Comment: I didn't express myself correctly. The continuity implies that if it has a smallest period $T$, then, since $2\pi$ is a period, $2\pi=kT$ for some natural $k$.